# Leaflet marker click callback on spiderfy

Tags: callback, openstreetmap, leaflet

Using the great spiderfier of George MacKerron https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet
there is a problem.

When clicked on a pin, the popup of it is showing up. That´s cool, as long as I don´t have overlapping pins, which I spiderfy.
The problem with spiderfied pins is the popup, which opens on the first click too, while it overlaps certain other pins of the spiderfied set.

Therefore, I need a click callback on the spiderfy-listener, which allows me to close the popup immediately after spiderfying. Or even better, directly before spiderfying the set.

The question is: How can I achieve a callback on the spiderfy-listener? Well, maybe its dumb to do it on that one, in that case please tell me what to do else. Thanks :)

My code which uses a whacky 20ms hack at the bottom, I don´t want to keep:

```
    // Kartendarstellung mit Spiderfier
    var map = L.map('basicMap').setView(new L.LatLng(position[0][0], position[0][1]), 13);
    map.doubleClickZoom.disable(); 
    var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map, {
        keepSpiderfied: true,
        nearbyDistance: 25,
        legWeight: 2
    });

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Kartendaten &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> und Mitwirkende, Lizenz: <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Bilddaten © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>'
    }).addTo(map);    

    for (var i = 1; i < <?php echo count($pos);?>; i++){
        switch(position[i][3]){
            case "B":
                marker = L.marker([position[i][0], position[i][1]],{icon: BIcon}).addTo(map);
                break;
            case "S":
                marker = L.marker([position[i][0], position[i][1]],{icon: SIcon}).addTo(map);
                break;    
        }
        // Marker ungeöffnet auf Karte setzen
        var popup = new L.popup();
        var content = position[i][2];
        // Marker-Inhalt zuweisen
        marker.bindPopup(content);
        // Spiderfier Marker setzen
        oms.addMarker(marker);
    }

    oms.addListener('spiderfy', function() {
        // Hack als Ersatz zu fehlendem Spiderfy-Marker-Click-Callback
        setTimeout( function() {
            map.closePopup();
        }, 20);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are binding the popup directly to the marker when you create it, rather than dynamically binding it when the oms layer is clicked. This is the recommended approach in the oms documentation https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet

I haven't tested this, but your code should look something like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i < <?php echo count($pos);?>; i++){
    switch(position[i][3]){
        case "B":
            marker = L.marker([position[i][0], position[i][1]],{icon: BIcon}).addTo(map);
            break;
        case "S":
            marker = L.marker([position[i][0], position[i][1]],{icon: SIcon}).addTo(map);
            break;    
    }

    // In your loop, store the popup content as a property of the marker
    marker.desc = position[i][2];  

    // Spiderfier Marker setzen
    oms.addMarker(marker);
}

// Delegate the click to the oms layer and dynamically create the popup based on the 
var popup = new L.Popup();
oms.addListener('click', function(marker) {
  // Set the popup content using the marker property set in the loop
  popup.setContent(marker.desc);
  popup.setLatLng(marker.getLatLng());
  map.openPopup(popup);
});
```